# Inserting a javascript web analytics client into a Neo4j Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, neo4j, web-analytics, matomo

I've [set up](https://thinklab.com/discussion/hosting-hetionet-in-the-cloud-creating-a-public-neo4j-instance/216) a public Neo4j Browser available at [neo4j.het.io](https://neo4j.het.io/browser/).

Since this a public instance, I'd like to collect information about who's using the service and how. I was hoping to add web analytics tracking to our Neo4j Browser. I personally use Piwik, although most solutions will probably also work for Google Analytics. Piwik is enabled using a [javascript tracking client](https://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide).

Does anyone know how to add this javascript so it executes in a Neo4j Browser? One option I thought of is including the script in the [HTML guide](https://neo4j.het.io/guides/hetionet.html) that is played on browser startup — however, this didn't seem to work, although I didn't exhaustively troubleshoot it. We're currently running Neo4j server version 3.0.2 and Neo4j browser version 1.1.6.

Comment: no answer to your question. But you should  at least enable password authentication in Neo4j. Otherwise nasty people will sooner or later cause damage to your data. Your database is currently open to the world.

Comment: You can edit `NEO4J_PATH/lib/neo4j-browser-x.y.z.jar/browser/index.html`.

Comment: @stefan-armbruster the whole point of our browser is to be public. It's a read only Neo4j instance hosted on a dedicated cloud virtual machine. Is there any specific risk you're worried about? We can always redeploy a fresh image in case of corruption.

Comment: Thanks @stdob-- that's a powerful and versatile solutation. If the [image tracker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015637/inserting-a-javascript-web-analytics-client-into-a-neo4j-browser#comment63477009_38016707) turns out to be too limited, I'll look into injecting the javascript directly into the Browser page code.

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons Neo4j Browser currently strips all Javascript from the custom browser guides, so you cannot add your Javascript tracking code there.

You have a few options though:

- host the javascript to load the tracking client and embed in an iframe in the browser guide. I think you will lose some tracking information, but this might be a good start
- use one of the single pixel image tracking services that track analytics by loading an invisible image (the kind used in email open tracking services)
- edit the Neo4j browser code to include your tracking javascript
- you can log the Cypher queries that are executed (by the server, not just in the browser) by setting `dbms.logs.query.threshold=0`. This will log all Cypher queries that are executed.

Comment: I added the single pixel tracking image to the autoplaying guide by adding teh following HTML: `<img src="https://piwik.dhimmel.com/piwik.php?idsite=7&rec=1" style="border:0" alt="" />`. Interestingly, it seems like I needed to [specify `rec=1`](http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_176/ "Piwik: How do I enable tracking for visitors that have disabled Javascript?") for the tracking to work.

Comment: Query logging would be a nice feature, which can be activated by setting `dbms.logs.query.enabled=true`. Unfortunately as of 3.0.3 the feature is only available in the Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

Also neo4j-browser is open source, so you can fork it and change it to your needs.

See: http://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@william-lyon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2954199/william-lyon) and [@stdob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989460/stdob), I got two methods to work.

## Tracking image in the guide

The [first method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38016707/4651668) uses a single pixel tracking image inserted into a guide that autoplays in each new Browser instance. For this solution, I added the following HTML to my guide:

`<img src="https://piwik.dhimmel.com/piwik.php?idsite=7&rec=1" style="border:0" alt="" />`

This solution was easy to implement, but requires autoplaying a guide. Additionally, the tracking image has limited tracking ability. For example, this method cannot identify the referring URL. Thus I decided to try out the javascript insertion method.

## Modifying the neo4j-browser jar

[This method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015637/inserting-a-javascript-web-analytics-client-into-a-neo4j-browser#comment63475359_38015637) modifies the source of Neo4j Browser webpage. Since I'm using a custom docker image to install Neo4j, this method could be implemented. Here is the [code I added to my Dockerfile](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet/blob/6e83b6ea6101bdece408d15079c0ceec1cc5c1e5/hetnet/neo4j/docker/Dockerfile#L13). The solution adds the Piwik javascript client to the `<head>` of `browser/index.html` inside `lib/neo4j-browser-*.jar`. Note that jar files are actually zip files.

Here is the [javascript I inserted](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet/blob/6e83b6ea6101bdece408d15079c0ceec1cc5c1e5/hetnet/neo4j/docker/files/piwik.html) -- you will have to customize the clients for your specific Piwik server details. I recommend this method if possible, since it gives you more feature rich analytics.